# Htmlunit driver has trouble with Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I wrote a Selenium test with java that I launched with the FirefoxDriver and it is executing fine in Firefox browser.

Then I am replacing FirefoxDriver with HtmlunitDriver like this:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

with

```
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
```

But then I got this error :

> It's missing ';' Before an instruction (http://local.project/bundles/app/js/socket.js#1)

This is the socket.js file :

```
class SocketHandler {
    constructor(url) {
        this.url = url;
        this.session = null;
    }

    ....
}
```

I suspect that it doesn't recognize the class declaration. Any idea how to correct that please?

Comment: Why you want to use the HtmlUnitDriver?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Because it uses less ressources than firefox

Comment: Better use PhantomJS then. `HtmlUnitDriver` is not best compatible driver for testing.

Comment: Is it compatible with Selenium? After somme search it seems like it is. I'am going to test that thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use PhantomJs. As PhantomJs is not so much maintain these days. You can use chromedriver in headless mode.

you just need to add options as headless as below :-

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
```

Please find complete code below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Workspace\\JmeterWebdriverProject\\src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

While if still you want to use phantomjs. then first download phantomjs binary from below location :-

http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Now use below code :-

```
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path","D:\\Workspace\\JmeterWebdriverProject\\src\\lib\\phantomjs\\phantomjs.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = null;
ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
cliArgsCap.add("--web-security=false");
cliArgsCap.add("--ssl-protocol=any");
cliArgsCap.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=true");
capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability(
PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
capabilities.setCapability(
PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_CLI_ARGS,new String[] { "--logLevel=2" });
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thank you it was really helpful. I'am doing some test loading with Selenium and even in headless mode I can't put more than 50 browsers before my computer starts "lagging". Do you know if there is some more chromeOptions than can use to "lighten" the browser ? Or if it's worth moving to PhantomJS? I need to reach 80 browsers simultaneously.

Comment: Yes you can try with phantomjs .. you can also go for selenium grid concept where your host will send instructions to slaves machine.. so using grid you need 2 machine which will run 40 instance each